# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\cdot\log\left(3^\frac{n}{1} + 3^\frac{n}{2} + \dots + 3^\frac{n}{n}\right)$

Tags: analysis, limits

> Calculate $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\cdot\log\left(3^\frac{n}{1} + 3^\frac{n}{2} + \dots + 3^\frac{n}{n}\right)$

I tried putting $\frac1n$ as a power of the logarithm and taking it out of the limit, so I got

$$ L = \log\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(3^\frac{n}{1} + 3^\frac{n}{2} + \dots + 3^\frac{n}{n}\right)^\frac1n $$

At this point I thought of the fact that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+a_2^n+\dots+a_k^n} = max\{a_1, a_2, \dots,a_k\}$ but this won't be of any use here, I guess. How can I calculate this limit, please?

Comment: Exponentials grow very fast. $3^n + 3^{n/2} + \ldots \approx 3^n$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+a_2^n+\dots+a_k^n} = \max\{a_1, a_2, \dots,a_k\}$ is exactly what you need - you have solved the problem yourself: $\max\{3,3^{1/2},...,1\}=3$ .

Comment: just take $a_k = 3^{1/k}$

Comment: You guys are right! I am looking at this after quite some time and I wonder how I couldn’t finish the problem after that idea came to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). For example in this case you have

$$\log 3 =\frac{\log(3^n)}{n} \leq \frac{\log(3^n+3^{n/2}+\cdots+3^{n/n})}{n} \leq \frac{\log(n \cdot 3^n)}{n} = \frac{\log{n}}{n}+\log 3$$

Now it is not hard to see that both surrounding sequences converge to $\log 3$, so the limit of the middle is $\log 3$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** $$0<3^{\frac n 2}+\cdots+3^{\frac n n}\le(n-1)3^{\frac n 2}=\frac{3^n}{3^{\frac n 2}/(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; the answer is log(3). Intuituvely, just like the example you have mentioned, the fastest growing term in the summation is 3^n therefore, one can ignore the other terms and proceed by simplifying (1/n log(3^n)) which yields 3. To have a good justification for "ignoring" other terms, you may write the summation as;
3^n+3^(n/2)+...=3^n(1+3^(-n/2)+...) 
and then write: log(3^n(1+3^(-n/2)+...)) =log(3^n)+log(1+3^(-n/2)+...)) 
the second term is indeed equal to log(1) which is zero. Therefore you may proceed by calculating lim 1/nlog(3^n) which is solved by moving the exponential to beforehandn of the log.

Comment: You may want to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for posting here, otherwise it's difficult to read properly.

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{n}\log (3^n)$ does not equal $3$.